# Excel VBA - Type mismatch error (Error number 13)

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code which will search the through Column A for a particular element and it will return the cell address of the searched element. But when i execute the code i am getting error number 13 stating Type mismatch. I have gone through whole bunch of codes but still not successful to counter the error.

Here goes my VBA code

```
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()

Dim WbEPC As Workbook, _
    WbCPT As Workbook, _
    WsEPC As Worksheet, _
    WsCPT As Worksheet, _
    FirstAddress As String, _
    WriteRow As Long, _
    cF As Range, _
    num As String

   Set WbEPC = Workbooks("EPC 1.xlsx")
   Set WbCPT = Workbooks("Control Power Transformers.xlsm")
   Set WsEPC = WbEPC.Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set WsCPT = WbCPT.Sheets("Sheet2")

  With WsEPC
       .Activate
       With .Range("A1:A10000")

   ' I am getting the error in the below Set cF module.

   Set cF = .Find(What:="CTPT", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
         MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

     num = cF.Address ' Here we will the get the cell address of CTPT 

            WsEPC.Range(cF.Offset(0, 1), cF.Offset(0, 2).End(xlDown)).Copy
            WriteRow = WsCPT.Range("E" & WsCPT.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            WsCPT.Range("E" & WriteRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

 End with
 End with
 End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you make sure that the `.Find` succeeds? You can do so by setting a breakpoint in the debugger at the line `num = cF.Address`, and checking for the result. I have suspicion that since you start the search down from the `ActiveCell`, you dont know where is this active cell. Why dont you start the search from the first cell (ì.e. `A1`)?

Comment: I would avoid nesting `With`-Statements like that. You can change `With WsEPC` and `With .Range("A1:A10000")` to `With WsEPC.Range("A1:A10000")` and remove one of the `End With`

Comment: @A.S.H - The .Find succeeded and it a has a value $A$14

Comment: The error message is an almost certain symptom that `.Find` fails. I reproduced it, even if some cells have the requested value but through a formula. It succeeds in Excel but fails in VBA. I kindly ask you to try again but without the parameter `LookIn:=xlFormulas` (leave it to default).

Comment: @A.S.H - Finally problem is resolved as you said there is no problem when in excel level but  it fails to run in VBA. I removed LookIn:=xlFormulas in the .Find() function and its working fine without any errors. Thanks a ton. have a good day ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to `After:=ActiveCell` argument

Try remove it, or add

```
.Range("A1").Activate
```

just before `Set cF` line

Comment: as i mentioned above i removed the LookIn:=xlFormulas parameter from .Find () function. Now its working fine.

Thank you!